# permanent changes in ubuntu on USB stick without installing Ubuntu

Tags: usb, encryption

1. I want to operate **ubuntu ver 14.0.4** from USB Stick **without install it on the PC** , but when I make an update , install software or make system configuration if I restart the machine I lose everything , ***is there is anything to make those changes permanent*** ?
2. ***Is it possible to make this USB stick encrypted*** ?

Comment: Sounds like you need an actual HDD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To retain all the changes that you make on the LiveUSB, you'll have to enable [Persistence](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCD/Persistence) on the USB drive.

You can achieve this with an application like [UNetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/).

Enter the amount of space which you wish to allocate on the USB drive for your data in the column marked in the image below.

[image]

All the changes you make, ie install applications, create files etc. will now remain on the USB drive and can be accessed even after a reboot.

Answer (score 0):

You can find instructions here: http://www.pendrivelinux.com/creating-an-ubuntu-live-usb-from-cd/ :)

"Persistence" is what they call it when you can save your settings and data and it's not just live.

It should be possible to make the individual folders that you save encrypted and require a password, the same way as when as booting your OS from your internal hard drive.